# Rails Ajax something wrong with escape_javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

Here I've set up a Rails App using Ajax, for some reason I can't get the Ajax response
on the erb View. I guess <%= escape_javaScript %> on create.js is something wrong.

below is flow to post item.

1. post "item" on edit.html.erb (Ajax)
2. item_controller def create
3. create.js
4. /users/_item.html.erb (render Ajax)

### edit.html.erb

```
<div class="content content-item">
  <ol>
    <%= form_tag('/items', method: :post, remote: true) do %>
    <input type="text" name="text" pattern=".*\S+.*" required  size="23" maxlength="23" autocomplete="off" class="header-btn">
    <%= submit_tag "submit" ,:class => "header-btn" %>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="content content-item">
   <ol>
     <% if @items.present? %>
       <div id="item-content">
         <%= render partial: "users/item", collection: @items %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </ol>
</div>
```

### item_controller

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(text: item_params[:text], user_id: current_user.id)

  #Ajax
  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'successfully'}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }

      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

### create.js (main point)

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: '/users/item', collection: 
@item ) %>").appendTo("#item-content");
//after submitting it makes textarea blank. 
$('form').find("textarea,:text,select").val("").end().find(":checked").prop("checked", false);
```

### _item.html.erb

```
<div class="idea-text">
 <div  class="checked-item_<%= "#{item_counter}"%>" >
     <%= item.text  %>
 </div>
</div>//The rest is omitted
```

posted data is completely saved in database. 
and I can see them on the terminal.

But doesn't show up on edit.html.erb. 
I think create.js should be something wrong.

### terminal(after posting)

```
Started POST "/items" for ::1 at 2019-02-25 11:32:55 -0800
Processing by ItemsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "text"=>"hello world", "commit"=>"submit"}
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 
3  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, commit
 (0.4ms)  BEGIN
SQL (40.8ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`text`, `user_id`, `created_at`, 
`updated_at`) VALUES ('hello world', 3, '2019-02-25 19:32:55', '2019- 
02-25 19:32:55')
(52.3ms)  COMMIT
Rendered users/_item.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered items/create.js.erb (4.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 151ms (Views: 22.9ms | ActiveRecord: 94.7ms)
```

Comment: The `edit.html.erb` doesn't go to the `create` action, it goes to the `edit` action.

Comment: Thank you for comment.  But method is Post, on  /users/edit.html.erb  though. It seems good till create.js response.

Comment: @item is not a collection. Try `render partial: '/users/item', locals: { item: 
@item }`

Comment: I used to do that, but I wanted to use "(variable name)_counter" . That's why I changed to use collection: @items instead of locals: {item: @item}.

Comment: @Ryoma and what is item_counter? Where do you define it?